# How to enable/disable button instead of select it ? (buttongroup)

Tags: java, swing, buttongroup

I have some buttons (JButton) and I want to disable the button which is "selected", so if you click on another button it become disable and all other enable. It's almost like `ButtonGroup` but instead of "select/deselect" it's with "enable/disable".

I don't know if something already exist to do it or what is the best approach.

- Extends `ButtonGroup` and override all function
- Create a custom `ButtonModel` and a `ButtonGroup` like
- Add an `ActionListener` (the same) for each button which disable current button and enable others
- ...

I think "Extends `ButtonGroup` ..." is the best one but I'm not sure which is why I ask.

How can I have a `ButtonGroup` like with enable/disable  ?

E.g :

First button disable : [image]
and when I click on the second one : [image]

nb: It will be used several times for different group of buttons

Answer (score 0):

Keep all of your desired buttons in a button group:

```
ButtonGroup buttonGroup  = new ButtonGroup();
buttonGroup.add(jbuttonA);
buttonGroup.add(jButtonB);
buttonGroup.add(jButtonC);
```

You could then just check whether your alternative button is selected by using [JButton#isSelected()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) to then (de)select your button group using [ButtonGroup#setSelected(ButtonModel,boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html).

Additionally you could make it prompt upon clicking using an anonymous action listener; this requires you to declare your outer components as `final` however.

IF you want to disable the `JButton` it may be sufficient to just use `JButton#setVisible(boolean)`.

Should you require further explanation let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your "alternative button". All buttons must be visible even the disable one and it must be disable but not selected. If you click on `jButtonB` then it become disable and`JButton` A and C enable, .... There is always only one which is disabled. So with your solution if I understand correctly it will not be selected but it will not be disable too.

Comment: @Duffydake - what is the purpose of disabling the button? Can't you just set its visibility to `false`? From your question, all you are doing is changing the icon (and its colour) once they are clicked. You can just add a flag to check whether the button is currently enabled/disabled and change the icon accordingly

Comment: @ Juxhin the purpose doesn't really matter. You can't know but I use a LAF and when something is disable it become black and white, I don't change any icon, ... on question images, I just extends `ButtonGroup` and override all functions with "setEnable".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example I made might help.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Example extends JFrame{

    private JButton b1 = new JButton("B1");
    private JButton b2 = new JButton("B2");

    private Listener listener = new Listener();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        b1.addActionListener(listener);
        b2.addActionListener(listener);

        add(b1);
        add(b2);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class Listener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == b1) {
                //Somehow loop through all your JButton group
                //And change button.setIcon(), etc.. properties..
                b1.setEnabled(false);
                b2.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b2) {
                b2.setEnabled(false);
                b1.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, maybe my question is not clear, but I don't need code I know at least 3 way on how to do it (even what you propose which is the most "basic" one), but I'm not sure if something else exist or either if what I've choose is good, images in question use the first method in my question (extends Buttongroup)